# Disable and enable button in js

Tags: javascript

i want to make a form with inputs and "submit" button. Idea is to disable button as long as inputs are empty or value of input not correctly (email validation).
I have my js code, but the problem is that, button starts at the beggining as disabled, but when i write something in first input it start to be not disabled, even if rest of inputs have not correct value.

My function:

```
  document.getElementById("my-button").disabled = true
  function inputValidator() {
            var $element = $(this);
         
            // for all input fields
            if ($element.val()) {
                $element.closest('.my-form__item').removeClass('error');
                document.getElementById("my-button").disabled = false;
            } else {
                $element.closest('.my-form__item').addClass('error');
                document.getElementById("my-button").disabled = true;
            }
            // for email field
            if ($element.attr('id') === 'email' && $element.val()) {
                if (!reg.test($element.val())) {
                    $element.closest('.my-form__item').addClass('error');
                    document.getElementById("my-button").disabled = true;
                } else {
                    $element.closest('.my-form__item').removeClass('error');
                    document.getElementById("my-button").disabled = false;
                }
            }
```

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: the button will remain disabled. add event listeners to the input fields and do the validation in the callback function. then disable/enable the button when appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over each element inside the form and check if one elements value length is zero. Note: Also the submit button needs a value in this implementation. A more native way would be to simply add the required tag to each input which also gives a good user experience.

### JS approach

```js
function validateForm() {
  let inputs = document.forms["example"].elements;
  let status = true;
  [...inputs].forEach((input) => {
    if(input.value.length == 0) status = false;
  });
  document.getElementById('submit').disabled = !status;

}
```

```html
<form id="example">
  <p>
    <label>First name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" onKeyup="validateForm()">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Last name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" onKeyup="validateForm()">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Email</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" onKeyup="validateForm()">
  </p>

  <p>
    <button disabled=true id="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

### Pure HTML Approach

```html
<form id="example">
  <p>
    <label>First name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" required>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Last name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" required>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Email</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" required>
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </p>
</form>
```